# Ways to get realtime response from remote machine

Tags: ajax, node.js, ssh

Here is the situation:
- I have a server to run ssh command into the remote machine (AP) to perform some system commands such as restarting wifi, network etc.

- I have a UI written to clients to achieve the above functions
- I want to show the process progress, outputs (e.g. the AP's output while running the above commands)
- Currently, I use AJAX to achieve this, but the limitation is that traditional AJAX mechanism only allows me to wait until the whole command has finished running.
- Now I want the server to give me feedback periodically (say 1s) and the client can display the data on the fly.

Is reverse ajax the best solution to achieve this purpose?

I am thinking of using the following
- node.js (blend with my existing Apache PHP and jQuery model)

Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX polling is one way to do this. As you can see it has some drawbacks. I prefer to do this with websockets. They give you a duplex, realtime connection between server and browser. 
This is perfect for your needs.

You can use variety of websocket libraries [available](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-ws-ajax). I use [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO).